# Where is the program or package gcjh?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, pdftk, gcj

I'm having trouble similar to [Unable to build pdftk from source on fedora machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787666/unable-to-build-pdftk-from-source-on-fedora-machine), but I'm having it on Ubuntu 13.04.

I've install `gcc-gcj`, which provides `gcj-4.8`.

I opened `Makefile.Debian`, and modified it as follows. So it finds the proper version of some of the GCC build tools:

```
export VERSUFF ?=-4.6
```

Next, I tried to `make`:

```
$ VERSUFF="-4.8"; make -f Makefile.Debian     
make -f Makefile -iC /home/jwalton/pdftk-2.02-dist/pdftk/../java all
...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jwalton/pdftk-2.02-dist/java'
gcjh-4.8 -force --classpath="/usr/share/java/libgcj-4.8.jar:/home/jwalton/pdftk-2.02-dist/java:."
    pdftk/com/lowagie/text/Anchor
/bin/sh: 1: gcjh-4.8: not found
...
gcjh-4.8 -force --classpath="/usr/share/java/libgcj-4.8.jar:/home/jwalton/pdftk-2.02-dist/java:."
    pdftk/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESFastEngine
/bin/sh: 1: gcjh-4.8: not found
```

Though I have installed `gcc-gcj`, it appears I don't have `gcjh`:

```
$ find /usr/bin -name gcjh
$ find /usr/local/bin -name gcjh
$
```

There is no `gcc-java` or `gcc-gcjh` packages:

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames | grep -i gcc-java
$ apt-cache pkgnames | grep -i gcc-gcjh
$ apt-cache pkgnames | grep -i gcjh
$
```

What is `gcjh`, and where can I find it for Ubuntu 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search, and I get http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gcjh&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any suggesting that the answer is `gcj-jdk`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm surprised `apt-cache` did not turn it up.

Answer (score 5):

#### For anyone in recent years trying to compile `pdftk` or otherwise looking for `gcj`

The `pdftk` package relied on `gcj`, which is the [GCC compiler for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java). GCJ was officially removed from GCC in September 2016, and by extension, discontinued by the package repositories themselves for the various distros. As a result of this, many notable systems have officially dropped the no-longer-buildable `pdftk` package itself from their repositories, including [Fedora](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2014-March/196367.html), [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/1757314) and [Cygwin](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2016-08/msg00656.html).

I gave up attempting to build `pdftk` for my own Cygwin system because of the `gcj` dependency and because I couldn't trust a tool from developers who insist on using dependencies that have been deprecated for 4 years now. An [email exchange here](https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit/issues/123#issue-52316206) from 2014 - two years before GCJ was finally dropped by GCC - cites the developer of `pdftk` as saying:

> Yes, I've heard that they're dropping support for libgcj. We have been
>   working on a new pdftk that doesn't depend on libgcj, but it is
>   currently pre-beta.

However, it seem nothing came from this "pre-beta", since the last time `pdftk` had an update *at all* [was in 2013](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/).

I personally had two options available to me: to install the Windows binary of the `pdftk`, which would result in an installation separate to the rest of my Cygwin environment, or to use a different but similar tool such as `qpdf`. Given what I now knew of the last time that `pdftk` had been  updated, I opted to use `qpdf` and so far haven't been disappointed. The one criticism I have of `qpdf` is that the website and documentation looks a lot less prettier compared to `pdftk`s, but the tool itself appears to have all of the same functionality as `pdftk`.

`qpdf` is also available and actively maintained on most other major Unix-like systems, including [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qpdf) and [Fedora](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-updates-x86_64/qpdf-8.4.2-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html).

For anyone who's still desperate to compile `pdftk` for a Linux distribution, for either workflow or legacy reasons, the [above-linked Github thread](https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit/issues/123) has some instructions that seem like they still work for a few people.